# Angular 2/4 - What is the best way to collect form data?

Tags: angular, dataservice

Let's say you're making a car configuration app in Angular, and you want a way to store all the users choices but you don't want to store it in local storage, session nor in a database until you have all the data. but how do you do it and what is the best way to do so?

I've looked at rxjs Subject's methodology and Observable Data Services methodology but it doesn't suit what i require. Before i go off and make my own type of data collection service, is there a methodology that already exists that will allow me too:

- Add data to a store that doesn't overwrite existing data unless told too.
- Read certain items from the store.

Comment: I'd suggest to check reactive forms before anything else. They already provide a model for the entire form. It's up to you how it will be synced with persistent storage.

Comment: rxjs observables accomplish exactly what you're looking for if you do it right. You should post what you tried with those so that someone can help you figure them out.

Comment: Do you need to save your current data after page reloading? If no - you can use behavior subject. If yes - local storage or db.